# Passing dynamic variable from routeprovider to controller

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, route-provider

I am trying to pass my dynamic variable from route to controller. I am using following code. However it is not working, It basically possing :slug, not the variable string i want. For example if I am trying to get /pages/web-dev-1 and hope to store web-dev-1 inside :slug and pass to controller, it only passes :slug.

```
$routeProvider.when('/pages/:slug',{
        templateUrl:'partials/service.php',
        controller: 'oneServiceController',
        params: ':slug'
    });
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service is for.